# When having a bidirectional relationship, how to avoid a field only when accessing from one side of the relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two classes :

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "id")
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "client_id")
private Long id;
private char gender;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SurveyData> survey = new ArrayList<SurveyData>(); }
```

And SurveyData:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "id")
public class SurveyData{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SURVEY_ID")
private Long Id;
private double score;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
public Client client; }
```

This way when I access SurveyData, I get Client model as a result too. And when I access Client, I get SurveyData too.
But my problem is this.
I have a query that returns SurveyData Based on a condition, so say I would have this as a JSON Result:

```
{id:1
 client:
        {name: Name,
         lastName: last,
         survey:[{
           score: 10,
             ///
          }]
```

How do I avoid getting the survey List as a result when accessing from SurveyData.
I cannot use JsonIgnore, because I have other methods where when I access Client model, I will need to be able to access survey model using the List.
Is there a way to do this ?

So, basically, only when calling SurveyData, I need to ignore the List survey in the Client class..else I need to use it.

Comment: what is the query that you are using

Comment: findTop5ByClient_GenderOrderByScoreDesc() on the SurveyRepository- [ I have a score field on the Survey class, and a gender field on the Client ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [@JsonView](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring). In the `Message` class sample, it provides a nice example using `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)` and `@JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)`, which is exactly what you're looking for.

```
public class View {
    interface Summary {}
    interface SummaryWithRecipients extends Summary {}
}

public class Message {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private LocalDate created;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String title;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private User author;

    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
    private List<User> recipients;

    private String body;
}
```

Now, depending on the annotation, it will either include or exclude the list of recipipients.

```
// excludes list of recipients
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@GetMapping("/")
public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
    return messageService.getAll();
}

// includes list of recipients
@JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
@GetMapping("/with-recipients")
public List<Message> getAllMessagesWithRecipients() {
    return messageService.getAll();
}
```